# Teleport in component from slot Vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-teleport

I want to create tabs component for my components library. I want `tabs` and `tab` components to work like this:

```
<b-tabs>
  <b-tab
    :title="'tab 1'"
    :is-active="false"
  >
    tab content1
  </b-tab>
  <b-tab
    :title="'tab 2'"
    :is-active="false"
  >
    tab content2
  </b-tab>
  <b-tab
    :title="'tab 3'"
    :is-active="true"
  >
    tab content3
  </b-tab>
</b-tabs>
```

So we have two components and they have some props including is-active which by default will be false.

The parent component - `tabs.vue` will be something like this

```
<template>
  <section :class="mode ? 'tabs--light' : 'tabs--dark'" @change-tab="selectTab(2)">
    <div :id="`tabs-top-tabId`" class="tabs__menu"></div>
    <slot></slot>
  </section>
</template>
```

here we have wrapper for our single `tab` which will be displayed here using slot. Here in this "parent" component we are also holding `selectedIndex` which specify which tab is selected and function to change this value.

```
  setup () {
    const tabId = Math.random() // TODO: use uuid;
    const data = reactive<{selectedIndex: number}>({
      selectedIndex: 0
    })

    const selectTab = (i: number) => {
      data.selectedIndex = i
    }

    return {
      tabId,
      ...toRefs(data),
      selectTab
    }
  }
```

**TLDR** Now as you guys might already noticed in `tab.vue` I have div with class `tabs__menu` which I want to teleport some stuff into. As the `title` props goes into `<tab>` component which is displayed by the slot in tabs.vue I want to teleport from tab to tabs.

My `tab.vue`:

```
<template>
  <h1>tab.vue {{ title }}</h1>
  <div class="tab" v-bind="$attrs">
    <teleport :to="`#tabs-top-tabId`" @click="$emit('changeTab')">
      <span style="color: red">{{ title }}</span>
    </teleport>
    <keep-alive>
      <slot v-if="isActive"></slot>
    </keep-alive>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, PropType } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String as PropType<string>,
      required: true
    },
    isActive: {
      type: Boolean as PropType<boolean>,
      required: true
    }
    // tabId: {
    //   type: Number as PropType<number>, // TODO: change to string after changing it to uuid;
    //   required: true
    // }
  }
})
</script>
```

However this `span` does not get teleported. When I run first snippet for this post I can't see it displayed and I don't see it in DOM.

[image: vue3 teleport]

Why teleported span doesnt display?

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue recently when using element-plus with vue test utils and Jest.
Not sure if this would help but here is my workaround.

```
const wrapper = mount(YourComponent, {
  global: {
    stubs: {
      teleport: { template: '<div />' },
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).